# Pulling 3 values from an html webpage to set variables for a led light on my Arduino Ethernet

Tags: html, arduino

I am trying to talk to my Arduino Ethernet via a webpage and change the rgb values of an led. I have the webpage set up the way I want. The only problem that I'm having is making the "Set Color" button return the red, green, and blue values from the text boxes and setting those values to make the led change colors. How do I take the values I input into the text boxes and set them in my getColors() ?

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Ethernet.h>
// MAC address from Ethernet shield sticker under board
byte mac[] = { /*MAC Address*/};
IPAddress ip(/*IP of Arduino server*/); 
EthernetServer server(80);  // create a server at port 80
String fileName="test.txt";

int ledRed = 3;
int ledGreen = 5;
int ledBlue = 6;
int sRed,sGreen,sBlue;

void setup()
{
  Ethernet.begin(mac, ip);  // initialize Ethernet device
  server.begin();           // start to listen for clients
  pinMode(ledRed, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(ledGreen, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(ledBlue, OUTPUT);
}

void loop()
{
  EthernetClient client = server.available();  // try to get client
  if(client) // got client?
  {          
    boolean currentLineIsBlank = true;
    while (client.connected()) {
        if (client.available()) {   // client data available to read
            char c = client.read(); // read 1 byte (character) from client
            // last line of client request is blank and ends with \n
            // respond to client only after last line received
            if (c == '\n' && currentLineIsBlank) {
                // send a standard http response header
                client.println("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
                client.println("Content-Type: text/html");
                client.println("Connection: close");
                client.println();
                // send web page
                client.println("<!DOCTYPE html>");
                client.println("<html>");
                client.println("<head>");
                client.println("<title>Arduino Web Page</title>");
                client.println("</head>");
                client.println("<body>");
                client.println("<h1>Hello from Arduino!</h1>");
                client.println("<p>A web page from my Arduino server</p>");
                client.println("<p style=\"color:red\">Red<form><input type=\"text\"></form></p>");
                client.println("<p style=\"color:blue\">Blue<form><input type=\"text\"></form></p>");
                client.println("<p style=\"color:green\">Green<form><input type=\"text\"></form></p>");
                client.println("<button type=\"button\"onclick=\"GetColors()\">Set Color</button>");
                client.println("</body>");
                client.println("</html>");
                break;
            }
            // every line of text received from the client ends with \r\n
            if (c == '\n') {
                // last character on line of received text
                // starting new line with next character read
                currentLineIsBlank = true;
            } 
            else if (c != '\r') {
                // a text character was received from client
                currentLineIsBlank = false;
            }
        } // end if (client.available())
    } // end while (client.connected())
    delay(1);      // give the web browser time to receive the data
    client.stop(); // close the connection
  } // end if (client)
}

void getColors(EthernetClient cl)
{
  if(Serial.available())
  {   
    //sRed=???
    //sBlue=???
    //sGreen=???
    analogWrite(ledRed,sRed);
    analogWrite(ledBlue,sBlue);
    analogWrite(ledGreen,sGreen);
  }
  else
    Serial.println("Unacceptable; try again.");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're creating a web page. Now you need to get the HTML of that webpage using a get/post request and parse the result you get as text (or build/look for an existing parser you can use) and get the values you want.

You would do this also with any tag/attribute/text you want to get from the web page you published.

Although if you're the one who's publishing the webpage, you already know those values, unless they could be changed via a web browser and then you need to do what's written above.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this library https://github.com/sirleech/Webduino.
It have an example with RGB values.

Or If you don't mind having a computer running a webserver, you could build yourself a nice webpage and send data to the arduino via telnet. (php)